# Cant add input and display the sum in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

To learn and study JavaScript, im trying to do a calculator, and as start i tried to do a sum operation by taking 2 input. But somehow there is a problem that i cant see. Can you help me?

Here is the code:

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <h1> JavaScript Test </h1>
        Sum The Nums Up!
        <br>
        <form>
            Number 1: <input type="text" name="n1" /><br>
            Number 2: <input type="text" name="n2" /><br>
        </form>
        <button id="b" onclick="func();" />Sum</button>
        <p id="b"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sum() {
                var nn1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
                var nn2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
                var sum = parseInt(nn1) + parseInt(nn2);
                document.write(sum);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change onclick="func();" to onclick="sum();"

Comment: And if you want to keep the "form" you have and display the results in `#b`, change `document.write(sum);` to `document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = sum;`

Comment: `<input type='text' name='n1'>` + `document.getElementById('n1')` won't fly: the input elements don't have an id property, only a name attribute. `document.write` is _evil_, BTW...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Not as evil as `evil()` ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Of course, that would be ***evil***, instead of merely _evil_ :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
function sum() {
```

With:

```
function func() {
```

This prevents you from assigning 2 different types / values to the same variable name.
(You've got an `sum` function and a `sum` variable in your question.)

---

Replace:

```
document.write(sum);
```

With

```
document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = sum;
```

This snippet adds the result of `sum` to `<p id="b"></p>` (So, the result may be: `<p id="b">18</p>`, for example), instead of arbitrarily adding it to the end of your HTML.

---

And finally, replace:

```html
Number 1: <input type="text" name="n1"/><br>
Number 2: <input type="text" name="n2"/><br>
```

With:

```html
Number 1: <input type="text" id="n1"/><br>
Number 2: <input type="text" id="n2"/><br>
```

`document.getElementById` looks for the `id` attribute in your HTML, not for the `name`.

Comment: Would the sum naming really matter ? I think sum() from onclick="sum();" would point to the function sum() with no problem and `.write(sum);` woul point wihtout problem to the `var sum`

Comment: Yea, I know the `var sum` is scoped to the function, but it's bad form to re-use names that way. Forget the `var` just once, and your function no longer exists after running it. It works, but it's "risky". That's why I suggested that change.

Comment: Hmmm true, `use strict` also helps in such cases :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:-

1. Change `onclick="func();"` to `onclick="sum();"` , you are calling the wrong/undefined function.

```html
<button id="b" onclick="sum();"/>Sum</button>
```

1. Assign input tags id as `n1` and `n2`, you have assigned them as name and are referring to them based on id `getElementById()`

```html
Number 1: <input type="text" id="n1"/><br>
Number 2: <input type="text" id="n2"/><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        <html>
        <body>
        <h1> JavaScript Test </h1>
        Sum The Nums Up!
        <br>
        <form>
        Number 1: <input type="text" id="n1" name="n1"/><br>
        Number 2: <input type="text" id="n2" name="n2"/><br>
        </form>
        <button id="b" onclick="sum();"/>Sum</button>
        <p id="b"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function sum()
        {
            var nn1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
            var nn2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
            var sum = parseInt(nn1) + parseInt(nn2);
            document.write(sum);
            }
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```